# PYODBC not closing connection to Access Database

Tags: pandas, ms-access, connection, pyodbc

I'm trying to load data from an Access databse using PYODBC.
The code I wrote is this:

```
#Connection Parameters
MDB = 'C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/EugeneVideo.mdb'
DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}'
PWD = 'PW'
pyodbc.pooling = False
con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={};DBQ={};PWD={}'.format(DRV,MDB,PWD))
SQL = """SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE c_state = 'CA' """
df = pd.read_sql_query(SQL, con)
csr = con.cursor()
csr.close()
con.close()
```

At the first time, it runs nicely.
The data is stored in a dataframe.
But if I try to run the script again, changing, for instance the filter parameter, python crashes.
I noticed that the LDB file is not being deleted after the first run, so, apparently, the connection is not being closed even I explicitly ask for that.
Where are the error? Is there a better way to assure that the connection will be closed?
I've already have tried the class methods, with similar results.

Cheers

Comment: Does it do the same thing if you scrap `csr = con.cursor()` and `csr.close()`? You appear to be opening a cursor to nothing, and that's a strange thing to do (normally you open a cursor, execute a query using that cursor, scroll over the result using that cursor, and then close the cursor, now you're just opening and closing one).

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue using pyodbc 4.0.30 and pandas 1.0.3 with Access 2013. For me the .ldb file does in fact get deleted and I can run the test script multiple times in succession. There must be something wrong with your particular environment.

Comment: Actually, I've added the close lines following some tips for similar problems. Originally they weren't there.
How can I use cursors to run a query?
I've tried in other machine, but there was a compatibility issue (Acceess 32 bits / Conda 64 bits), so I followed this tip:
https://datatofish.com/how-to-connect-python-to-ms-access-database-using-pyodbc/

I've unistalled Office 2016, installed de Microsoft package and re-installed Office 2016, but this time with the 64 bits version.

A friend of mine said that it works for her, so I'm trying to see where is the problem.

I'll give a try.

Comment: I've just tested on my personal machine. Office 2016 64 bits and Conda 64 bits.
Prior of Office installation I've installed the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable just to be sure.
Now it's working as I expected, the code has no cursor on it.
Still like to hear about the use of cursors do run queries, though.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by enabling VB in File -> Options -> Trust Center.